# Animating an object to disappear behind a wall

Tags: animation, transparency

This is a little difficult to explain, but let's say you have an object which you want to act like a ghost and pass through a wall. Easy enough. Now, make the object disappear by passing through a wall, but make the wall transparent as well so that all you see is the object disappear as it moves past a certain point...

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Edit: It could look like this, but imagine the wall is invisible as well. [image]

Comment: hello do you have an image showing what you want?

Comment: @moonboots added a picture.

Comment: do you mean that at one point the wall becomes half visible on its whole surface?

Comment: So basically you want to see the ghost approach the wall plane from behind before passing through?

Comment: For the best effect you're probably in the realm of compositing two view layers together, one with just the wall and another with a transparent plane that governs the ghost effect while letting you see the ghost on the "non-visible" side of the wall.

Comment: The picture shows the object passing through, but I'm hoping to make the object invisible until it passes through the wall layer to the camera side, if that makes sense.

Comment: Basically, my end goal is to take the animation and stick the image sequence (with the transparent background) into a video in VSE, and combine the animation with live footage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a boolean modifier on the moving object.

Set it to Difference mode and choose the wall as the boolean object.

Watch to see how it looks:

[image: GIF of a booleaned monkey in Blender.]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the *Holdout* option: Create a plane, enable its *Holdout* option in the *Object panel > Visibility*:

[image]

In the *Render* panel, activate the *Film > Transparent* option:

[image]

Your wall is now alpha transparent, you can render your object then mix it with your scene, either in the *Compositor* or in the *Video Sequencer*:

[image]

Comment: Poor Suzanne!!you are not an animal lover!!!

Comment: don't worry she's only travelling through dimensions

Comment:  ok, then i just hope she's doing well :D

Comment: I hope so, I have no news since she left, and I don't know how to bring her back from behind the holdout plane   :/   please heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelp

Comment: maybe try move the holdout plane....? 

Comment: I can't, I made it invisible, remember

Comment: Oh nooooooooooooo

Comment: @moonboots thank you for that!